# Kafka streams app seperate reads from writes

Tags: java, stream, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am pretty new to Kafka and Kafka Streams so please bear with me. I would like to know if I am on the right track here.

I am writing to a Kafka topic at the moment and try to access the data through a rest service. The raw data kind of needs to be transformed before it will be accessed.

What I have so far is a producer that writes the raw data into a topic.

**1.)** Now I want streams App (should be a jar running in a container) that just transforms the data in my desired shape. Following the materialized view paradigm here.

Over simplified version of 1.)

```
    KStreamBuilder builder = new KStreamBuilder();

    KStream<String, String> source = 
    builder.stream("my-raw-data-topic");

    KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(builder,props);
    KTable<String, Long> t =  source.groupByKey().count("My-Table");
    streams.start();
```

**2.)** And another streams App (should be a jar running in a container) that justs holds the `KTable` as some sort of Repository which can be accessed via a wrapping rest service.

Here I am kind of stuck with the proper way to work with the api.
What is the bare minimun to access and query a `KTable`? Do I need to assign the transformation topology to the builder again?

```
KStreamBuilder builder = new KStreamBuilder();
KTable table = builder.table("My-Table"); //Casting?
KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(builder, props);

RestService service = new RestService(table); 
// Use the Table as Repository which is wrapped by a Rest-Service and gets updated reactivly
```

Right now this is pseudo code

Am I on the right path here? Does is make sense to separate **1.)** and **2.)**? Is this the indented way to work with streams to materialize views? For me, it would have the benefit to scale up the writes and the reads via container independently where I see more traffic.

How is the repopulating of the KTable handled on a crash of either **1.)** or **2.)**. Is this done via replication to the streaming api or is this something I would need to address via code. Like resetting the cursor and reply the events?

Answer (score 0):

Couple of comments:

In your code snippet (1) you modify your topology after you handed the builder into the `KafkaStreams` constructor:

```
KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(builder,props);
// don't modify builder anymore!
```

You should not do this but first specify you topology and afterwards create the `KafkaStreams` instance.

About splitting you application into two. This can make sense to scale both parts independently. But it's hard to say in general. However, if you do spit both, the first one needs to write the transformed date into an output topic and the second one should read this output topic as a table (`builder.table("output-topic-of-transformation")` to serve the REST requests.

For accessing the store of the KTable, you need to get a query handle via the provided store name:

```
ReadOnlyKeyValueStore keyValueStore =
streams.store("My-Table", QueryableStoreTypes.keyValueStore());
```

See the docs for further details:

http://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide.html#interactive-queries

Comment: Thx for the reply. Is there a difference between StateStore and KTable. Because I am writing to a table right now and the "rest service" does not find the KTable via your 3rd snippet. I am accessing it with streams.store("Table-Name",..) Does it have to be a StateStore?

Comment: For this case it's the same thing. When you get a KTable, you do not name the KTable, but it's internal store. (Note, that the parameter name is `storeName` on the count method). So not sure why the store is not found. Might be a bug in you RestService implementation.

Comment: thx, might be the case I got "org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.InvalidStateStoreException: the state store, countByApi, may have migrated to another instance." In a Single instance env on docker - and the table is visible as topic via command line.

Comment: added another question for the exception above because it's topic on its own